# How to differentiate $\ln(a^x)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms

Can someone give me the process to differentiate this (with respect to $x$)?

$$
\ln(a^x)
$$

Comment: It might be worth looking into the chain rule of differentiation.
You have a function composed with another function there. ^_^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $$\ln(a^x) = x\ln a,$$ you can see that this function is in fact linear in $x$. (Note that $\ln a$ is just some constant.) The derivative is therefore $1 \cdot \ln a= \ln a.$

Comment: (+1) Clever! Most would go with chain rule though.

Comment: It's exactly what I was thinking but in the book "Calculus Made Easy" they differentiate

$-a*x*ln(a^x)$

and they found

$(1/y)*(dy/dx) = -ax*a^x*ln(a)-a*ln(a^x)$

and I don’t understand why because using the rule of differentiating a product I don’t found the same answer.

Comment: @MathNoob I think a lot of math students get used to applying rules without contemplating what lies before them. The chain rule is possible, of course, but it's so much more complex than necessary here. Always simplify first! :)

Comment: @geora It doesn't sound like the book is making calculus very easy at all. The function you wrote down is just $kx^2$, where $k = -a\ln a$, so its derivative is $2kx$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Use the fact that $$a^x = e^{x\ln a}.$$